# How to access variable from another view in parent view in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one view "CancelRow"

```
struct CancelRow: View {
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    init(isSelected: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isSelected = passenger.isSelected
    }

   @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
    HStack {
       Text(verbatim: "Hello, \(isSelected)")
    }
```

I have another view i which i want to show button active or not based on "isSelected" from "CancelRow"

// AnotherVIew

```
CancelRow(isSelected: .constant(false))
    Spacer()
    SubmitButtonView(buttonTitle: title, buttonCallBack: {
        goToOtherScreen()
    }, isActive: isSelected ) // how to access this variable from  "CancelRow"
```

but i am not sure how to access variable from another view..and if value of "isSelected" is changed in "CancelRow" how to update that value in another view?

Thank you for help

Comment: This very much depends on what the relationship is between the two views, are you creating one view from within the other or are they unrelated?

Comment: why don't you use a global shared varaible which can be accessed from any of your code

Comment: CancelRow is child view

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship beetween your views is "parent" (or *composition*), then you can use `@Binding` property wrapper.
Then your `SubmitButtonView` will have a property

```
@Binding var isActive: Bool
```

and you'll call

```
SubmitButtonView(buttonTitle: title, buttonCallBack: {
        goToOtherScreen()
    }, isActive: $isSelected )
```

from `CancelRow`.

Comment: Thank you for answer but what to write in CancelRow? how should i access it?

Comment: @NewiOSDev it needs to be the other way around, `@Binding` should be in CancelRow and `@State` in the parent view

Comment: I am using init method in CancelRow..so not sure how to do it?

Comment: @NewiOSDev please post your full code of both `CancelRow` and `SubmitButtonView` - otherwise I can't guess what are you specifically struggling with