# How to get variable value of child view in parent view on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one view "CancelRow", in which value of isSelected is changing

```
     struct CancelRow: View {
            @Binding var isSelected: Bool
        
            init(isSelected: Binding<Bool>) {
                self._isSelected = isSelected
            }
        
           @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
            HStack {
               Text(verbatim: "Hello, \(isSelected)")
            }

            CustomCheckbox(checkboxType: .withTrailingLabel, 
             checkboxTitle: "", isActive: $canCancel, isSelected: $isSelected)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
                    isSelected.toggle()
                }
            }
```

I have another view i which i want to show button active or not based on "isSelected" from "CancelRow"

// AnotherVIew

```
CancelRow(isSelected: .constant(false))
    Spacer()
    SubmitButtonView(buttonTitle: title, buttonCallBack: {
        goToOtherScreen()
    }, isActive: isSelected ) // how to access this variable from  "CancelRow"
```

Comment: State should be owned by a parent view and passed to child views — you shouldn’t try to reach into a child or sibling view’s state

Comment: @jnpdx can you plz help me with code..i tried sample solution without init method..but not sure how to access variable in "CancelRow" with init method

Comment: the "isSelected" value is false or true.. is come to know in CancelRow only how can i pass that from parent ..plz suggest

Comment: Use @State on the parent view and pass it to the child views instead of using .constant, which can’t update anyway

Comment: Please do not post the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519752/how-to-access-variable-from-another-view-in-parent-view-in-swiftui) question twice

Comment: @jnpdx yes my doubt is how to pass as i am using init method..not able to pass...can you plz provide example

Comment: I don’t know what passenger is in your example, so I can’t alter it. I wouldn’t use in it at all unless you have to.

Comment: @jnpdx its just for getting bool value..i updated question

Comment: What is xyz? Still doesn’t make any sense. Why aren’t you using what you are passing in?

Comment: @jnpdx I updated..can you help me with code as i am not sure where i am doing wrong..may be an example?

Comment: Please study [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford's CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu). You will find many ways of handling these issues from these links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, state should be owned by a parent view and then passed to the child views.

In your case, you don't *actually* need to use a custom initializer for `CancelRow` in the example you gave (you could rely on just the synthesized initializer), but as request, this uses an initializer.

```
struct CancelRow: View {
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool
    
    init(isSelected: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isSelected = isSelected
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(verbatim: "Hello, \(isSelected)")
            Button("Toggle") {
                isSelected.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubmitButtonView : View {
    var buttonTitle : String
    var buttonCallBack : () -> Void
    var isActive : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Submit: \(isActive ? "true" : "false")")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSelected = false
    
    var title : String {
        "Title"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CancelRow(isSelected: $isSelected)
            SubmitButtonView(buttonTitle: title, buttonCallBack: {
                goToOtherScreen()
            }, isActive: isSelected )
        }
    }
    
    func goToOtherScreen() {
        print("Navigate")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer ..the only issue i am having is getting issue as  "value of type 'Bool' to type 'Binding<Bool>'" ..i just updated question ..please suggest with this

Comment: I don’t understand where ‘data’ comes from in your new update. Instead, just use the code like I provided in my answer. It doesn’t make sense to pass in a binding and then not use it…

Comment: yeh got it..but but in my condition i am having checkbox..which is in "CancelRow" itself...means "isSelected" is changing in "CancelRow"

Comment: I'm not really sure what that means. It sounds like you want to pass a different state to CancelRow and SubmitButtonView, which is basically the opposite of what your question says.

Comment: the isSelecteds.toggle() i am using in "CancelRow"..sorry for confusion

Comment: I don't know what that means. In your question, you asked how to access the `isSelected` from `CancelRow` in `SubmitButtonView` -- I've shown you how to do that. Now, it sounds like you want something else (like the added `data` you edited into your question). Can you clarify what it is that you want?

Comment: I have updated my question..everything is same only thing is "isSelected" value is changing in "CancelRow" itself which i want to use in another view

Comment: Sorry, doesn't make any sense to me -- just adding `.onTapGesture { isSelected.toggle() } }` floating in the middle of nowhere doesn't clarify what the issue is -- the code you've added doesn't compile. And, you're using a variable (`data`) that has no explanation of where it came from.

Comment: Updated my question with clear...i am using customcheckbox..on click of checkbox button should unable disable..but button is in another struct

Comment: Your code doesn't come close to compiling. Please include a [mre]. Again, I'd encourage you to look at my answer and the other answer here, as they both show how to own state at a parent level and pass it down to a child view, which still seems to be the crux of the issue (from what I can figure out from your question).

Comment: you are answer is perfect for my solution with only one diff... i want isSelected.toggle()  in "CanceRow" instead of "AnotherView"...my value is changing in child and not in parent

Comment: Okay -- see updated answer. I just moved the button to the `CancelRow`

Comment: yeah..thats the issue..after moving toggle to "CancelRow" its not working ..means button in anotherview is always disabled

Comment: No, it's not -- please run *exactly* the code that I gave you. I've just tested it and it runs fine. Note that your code *can't* be run since it doesn't compile, so likely you have some difference that you've created when applying the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is this concept of `Source of truth`. In oversimplified terms, you need to have a `@State private var` in one of your structs. If that `@State private var` holds any information some other struct would like to use, the second struct should have `@Binding var` and be initialised from the first struct with the value of `@State private var`.

In code below struct `AnotherView` is the source of truth, it has `@State private var`, and other structs have `@Binding` and are initialised with value of that `@State private var`.

struct AnotherView:

> ```
> @State private var isSelected = false
>
> var body: some View {
>     VStack {
>         CancelRow(isSelected: $isSelected)
>         
>         Spacer()
>         
>         SubmitButtonView(isSelected: $isSelected)
>     }
> }
> ```

struct CancelRow:

> ```
> @Binding var isSelected: Bool
>
> var body: some View {
>     Text(isSelected ? "I'm selected" : "I'm not selected")
> }
> ```

struct SubmitButtonView:

> ```
> @Binding var isSelected: Bool
>
> var body: some View {
>     Button {
>         // do something on tap
>     } label: {
>         Text("Button text")
>     }
> }
> ```